# Xpath to get content of parent tag and child tag together

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div class="inner_body_left">
<li>
Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "
<a target="_blank" href="/events/CES_TVR_LAKE_2014_brochure_2FEb2014.pdf">Conservation   of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats</a>
", 13-15th November 2014
</li>
</div>
```

Here I want to get "Lake 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats".Is there a way to get both the content of li tag and a tag using single Xpath expression? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below **XPATH**, using [`string-join`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) :

```
string-join(//li/text(),"")
```

**output**

```
Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "", 13-15th November 2014
```

Or, to meet close to your need, using [`translate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-translate) :-

```
translate(string-join(//li/text(),""),'",','')
```

**output**

```
Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on  13-15th November 2014
```